# Deleted flag in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a `Deleted` flag (`bit`) column. How it is possible to realize it?

At this column following condition:

- If a record is new or updated, set to 1
- If deleted from source, set to 0

I think it's possible to make in merge statement. But I don't know how to do this. Or maybe there's another way?

Comment: Simple as `DELETE YourTable WHERE FlagColumn=1` ? (I'm actually not sure how you set 1 or 0...) According to your edit it should rather be `WHERE FlagColumn=0` ... **Carefull with real data!!!**

Answer (score 1):

You may want to double check your requirements, because the norm for a `Deleted` flag would be `0` for Not Deleted and `1` for Deleted. `0` is false, and `1` is true. That's so common, in fact, that I'm just going to assume that's what you wanted.

As for setting it with a [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), you'd want to do something like:

```
MERGE MyTable as Target
USING YourTable as Source ON
    Target.Id = Source.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    --Exists in both Source and Target
    UPDATE SET Deleted = 0 /* include other columns to update here */
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
    --Source was deleted
    UPDATE SET Deleted = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    --Source was added
    INSERT (Id, Deleted /* include other columns to insert here */)
    VALUES (Source.Id, 1 /* include other columns to insert here */);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a merge statement to do this:

```
merge into myTable using SourceTable
on myTable.pk = sourcetable.pk    
when matched then update set 
/*add any update columns here*/
Deleted = 0    
when not matched by target then insert
(pk, abcd, deleted)
values
(pk, xyz, 0)
when not matched by source then update set Deleted = 1
```

This will insert any rows that do not exist into the target table. This will update any matching rows and any rows in the destination but not the source will have the flag updated to 1.